# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a method that build huffman tree which is as follows:

```
def buildTree(tuples) :
    while len(tuples) > 1 :
        leastTwo = tuple(tuples[0:2])                  # get the 2 to combine
        theRest  = tuples[2:]                          # all the others
        combFreq = leastTwo[0][0] + leastTwo[1][0]     #enter code here the branch points freq
        tuples   = theRest + [(combFreq,leastTwo)]     # add branch point to the end
        tuples.sort()                                  # sort it into place
    return tuples[0]            # Return the single tree inside the list
```

but while I feed the function with following parameter:

```
[(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'g'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'a'), (5, 'e')]
```

I get the error as

```
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in buildTree
    tuples.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'
```

While debugging I found the error was in `tuples.sort()`.

Comment: `leastTwo` is a tuple of tuples, which you then wrap in *another* tuple with `combFreq` (an integer). You can't compare that *inner* tuple with the strings in the second element of each of the other tuples.

Comment: In other words, you can only add `(int, str)` tuples, not `(int, ((int, str), (int, str)))` tuples.

Comment: Now, if you only wanted to sort on the **first** value in each tuple, you need to specify a sort key that extracts that.

Comment: Not that I would use sorting here; use a priority queue instead (see [How to implement Priority Queues in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9969236)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is thrown because you are creating inner nodes in `(priority, (node, node))` form. For equal priorities, Python then tries to compare a symbol from a leaf node (so the second element in a `(priority, symbol)` node tuple) with the `(node, node)` tuple from an inner node:

```
>>> inner = (combFreq, leastTwo)
>>> inner
(2, ((1, 'b'), (1, 'd')))
>>> theRest[1]
(2, 'c')
>>> theRest[1] < inner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'
```

For building a huffman tree, if you want to sort your array of nodes, you only really need to sort on the priority, ignoring the rest of the tuples (symbols or child nodes):

```
tuples.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])
```

With that correction, your `buildTree()` function produces a tree:

```
>>> buildTree([(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'g'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'a'), (5, 'e')])
(15, ((6, ((3, 'a'), (3, ((1, 'g'), (2, 'c'))))), (9, ((4, ((2, 'f'), (2, ((1, 'b'), (1, 'd'))))), (5, 'e')))))
```

Personally, I'd use a priority queue instead, avoiding sorting each time. See [How to implement Priority Queues in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969236/how-to-implement-priority-queues-in-python)

Comment: Thank You so much Martijn Pieters .People like you make the world beautiful.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I am experiencing the exact problem with a priority queue heappush. I have data in the form `heapq.heappush(heap, (priority, (n,v,w)))`. How can I force the queue to only consider the first element as above for sort(). The length of the tuple can vary.

Comment: @AngusTheMan: insert a tie breaker that's orderable and never equal with any other tie breaker value. Like the next value of an [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count): `_tiebreaker = itertools.count()`, then `heapq.heappush(heap, (priority, next(_tiebreaker), (n,v,w)))`.

Comment: @AngusTheMan: what that does is let the `heapq` module compare priorities, and for equal priorities, order by the tie-breaker value. Because those are never equal but are orderable, you keep Python from trying to compare the `(n, v, w)` tuples.

Comment: @AngusTheMan: another option is to wrap your `(priority, (...))` items in a custom class that implements its own ordering (perhaps using [`functools.total_ordering()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)) and in the implementation just compare priorities.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Decided to use the first option, very helpful thank you.