# Aggregate list column in DataFrame with custom function

Tags: python, pandas

### Task

I would like to custom aggregate my DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2], 'b': [[(1,2,3),(4,5),(6,)],[(7,8),(9,10)],np.NaN,[(11,12),(13,)],np.NaN], 'c': [1,2,3,4,5]})

   a                          b  c
0  1  [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6,)]  1
1  1          [(7, 8), (9, 10)]  2
2  1                        NaN  3
3  2          [(11, 12), (13,)]  4
4  2                        NaN  5
```

such that the lists in column `b` are extending each other per group. The result shall be

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [[(1,2,3),(4,5),(6,),(7,8),(9,10)],[(11,12),(13,)]], 'c': [6,9]})

   a                                           b  c
0  1  [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6,), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  6
1  2                           [(11, 12), (13,)]  9
```

### Attempted Solution

I was going with

```
def mylistaggregator(l):
    return [item for sublist in l.tolist() for item in sublist]

df. \
    groupby('a', sort=False). \
    agg({'b': mylistaggregator,
         'c': 'sum'})
```

but get

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

and are not sure what the solution would be. I also tinkered around with lambda, but did not get anywhere.

### Additional information

Running

```
types = []
for i in df.b:
    types.append(str(type(i)))
np.unique(types)
```

for my actual dataset returns

```
array(["<class 'float'>", "<class 'list'>"], 
      dtype='<U15')
```

Comment: How is that a bad question? It has a MWE and everything and I could not find the solution on the web.

Comment: Usually, that error implies that there are null values in the column. Null values in pandas are represented as floats. try `df = df.fillna([])` so the null values can be processed the same as the non null values.

Comment: @user2583933: TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need filter out `NaN`s:

```
def mylistaggregator(l):
    return ([item for sublist in l.tolist() if isinstance(sublist,list) for item in sublist])
```

Or:

```
def mylistaggregator(l):
    return([item for subl in l.tolist() if not isinstance(subl, float) for item in subl])



df1 = df. \
    groupby('a', sort=False). \
    agg({'b': mylistaggregator,
         'c': 'sum'})

print (df1)
                                            b  c
a                                               
1  [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6,), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  6
2                           [(11, 12), (13,)]  9
```

Another solution is replace `NaN`s to `[]`:

```
def mylistaggregator(l):
    return ([item for sublist in l.tolist() for item in sublist])

s = pd.Series([[]], index=df.index)
df['b'] = df['b'].combine_first(s)
#or
#df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(s)

df1 = df. \
    groupby('a', sort=False). \
    agg({'b': mylistaggregator,
         'c': 'sum'})

print (df1)
                                            b  c
a                                               
1  [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6,), (7, 8), (9, 10)]  6
2                           [(11, 12), (13,)]  9
```

Comment: The solutions work on the example dataset, but on my real dataset I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'`. I added some additional information about the columns datatypes.

Comment: Hmmm, hard answer, because I have no data returning error. Last solution works?

Comment: No, none of the solutions work. Any idea how to debug? `np.unique(df.b)` is `array([[], [(8338, 8339)], [(8338, 8339, 8340)],
       [(8338, 8339, 8340, 8341)], [(8338, 8339, 8340, 8341, 8343)],
       [(8339, 8340)], [(8339, 8340, 8341)], [(8339, 8340, 8341, 8343)],
       [(8340, 8341)], [(8340, 8341, 8343)], [(8341, 8343)]], dtype=object)` after `fillna`.

Comment: There has to be some problem with [tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913043/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-tuple-and-str). Is possible add to `def mylistaggregator(l):`  - `print (l)` and check if some weird nested tuples if error is raised?

Comment: It is happening in the groupby (my column `a` is a bit more complex). I solved it by grouping on `df['a_str'] = df.a.astype(str)`.

Comment: One idea - Instead `groupby('a', sort=False). ` use `groupby(df['a'].astype(str), sort=False).`, then is not necessary helper column.

Comment: No, because it is list and pandas try automatically convert it to one item Series. Only works fillna or combine_first by another Series full of `[]`. Pandas works, but things are complicated with lists or another nested structures.

Comment: Just to clarify for later readers: I asked if I could use `fillna([])`, but deleted, when realising that this does not work, but before realising that jezrael had answered.

Comment: If you want, I can delete coment.