# Finding value in a priority queue in python

Tags: python, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Is there a good way to delete values from the class `queue.PriorityQueue()` without ruining the priority queue? I guess theoretically I could make a loop that will `get` all the values until I reach the one I need, and insert all of the other ones back one without including the deleted node.  This seems like overkill though.  Is there a better way?

Edit: I'm trying to make a priority queue of nodes with the key being the cost to get to said node.  If I find a cheaper way of getting to the node I would like to replace it on the priority queue with the cheaper cost.

Comment: Maybe, but if you want to peek at other values, then PriorityQueue isn't the data-structure you want. Tell us more about the use-case: do you want to find the top-n, nth-largest or what? In any case sounds like you really need some other data-structure.

Comment: This definitely indicates a problem with the choice of data structure or algorithm.

Comment: I added some clarification...

Comment: Are you writing Djikstra's shortest path algorithm?

Comment: No, I'm trying to implement the A* algorithm.

Comment: This isn't the way you implement A*. You keep a separate data-structure for each node, (lower-cost is better). You don't keep one giant priority-queue mixing all nodes! That would indeed be painful. I don't see that you need a priority-queue on each node; for each node you only need to keep the one lowest-cost path. You are using an admissible heuristic, right?

Comment: I am using the manhattan distance as the admissible heuristic.  Wouldn't I need a priority queue that keeps track of all the nodes that have been looked at, sorted by their cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `queue` module and its classes are tools primarily meant to be used for synchronization (multi-threading/multi-processing), rather than being pure data structure.

Perhaps you'll find any of that answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407734/a-generic-priority-queue-for-python) suits your needs, or just use `heapq` directly.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a good way to delete any arbitrary value in priority queue. You can only extract top (min/max) element from priority queue.

A set data structure (balanced binary search tree) would be better, because you can find and delete node in O(log n).