# TypeError in PriorityQueue custom class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, queue

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

class NewQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=None):
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self, maxsize)

    def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
        PriorityQueue.put(self, item)


queue = NewQueue()

queue.put('abc')
```

I'm trying to create a custom class of PriorityQueue, but I get the
following error:

```
    PriorityQueue.put(self, item)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

Why does this happen and how could I make this custom class work?

Comment: there is an example on how to use PriorityQue on
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407734/a-generic-priority-queue-for-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the call to `queue.put` but the fact that you pass `None` as `maxsize`. If you want to have an unlimited queue use `0` as `maxsize`.

The error occurs in `put` because there it checks if `maxsize` is larger than `0` which will fail for `None`.

So just change the definition of `__init__`

```
class NewQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a queue with `maxsize=None`. Try istantiating your object using

```
queue = NewQueue(0)
```

or change your `__init__` signature:

```
def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
```